# Trying to have to columns with timestamp on google sheet

Tags: javascript

Column 11 is working fine (Last modified date) but column 12 (entered date) is not showing me any result help me find the problem with this code

```
function onEdit(e) {

     var row = e.range.getRow();  
     var col = e.range.getColumn();

if(col >= 1 && col <= 6 && row > 1){

            e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11).setValue(new Date());

            if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue() == ''){

              e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(new Date());
        }
    } }
```

Comment: For the if statement, shouldn't you use `getValue()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `setValue` function when checking inside the if condition. I need to have `getValue()`. Because when you check in if you `setValue()`, you set the value. The result is always `true` or always `false` :)